# Visual studio does not detect changes in header files

Tags: c++, header, visual-studio-2013, build-process

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 and I realized changing the header files does not trigger a build. I have to "touch" the corresponding ".cpp" file, or rebuild the whole project so the changes in ".h" file are considered. I did not have this problem before in Visual studio 2013 Ultimate. I tried disabling precompiled headers since I am not using it, but the problem still exists. I can clean and rebuild every time, but it is very time-consuming since the project is relatively large.